# Is any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ the countable union of almost disjoint boxes?

Tags: general-topology

Is any closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^d$ the countable union of almost disjoint boxes?

---

The theorem holds for open sets, and I'm having trouble either proving it for closed sets or finding a counterexample.

---

Edit: ah, certainly the closed line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(1,1)$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is a counterexample, yet closed line segments parallel to the axes *are* boxes, and thus the result holds for them.

With that in mind, does the result hold for $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: What about the Cantor set?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Yes! That's a counterexample. If you post that as an answer I will accept it (:

Comment: Wikipedia is telling me there are a variety of definitions of almost disjoint. Which definition do you mean?

Comment: @gist076923 I use "almost disjoint" as "having disjoint interiors".

Comment: If the line does not work, what about a circle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Cantor set is a counterexample.